# Should Cocos2D take EAGLview from openFrameworks, or vice versa?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, openframeworks, eaglview

Trying to get [Cocos2D](http://cocos2d-iphone.org) and [openFrameworks](http://openFrameworks.cc) to play nicely together on `iOS`. Both want to use `GL` / `EAGLview`, and of course they can't just both do `glView = [[EAGLView alloc] init]` because you can't have two root views. One has to `init` and the other one needs to have its `glView` pointer assigned to the other. What I'm doing right now:

```
#ifdef __COCOS2D__
  glView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];
#else // this is the standard openFrameworks GL init code
    glView = [[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds andDepth:iPhoneGetOFWindow()->isDepthEnabled() andAA:iPhoneGetOFWindow()->isAntiAliasingEnabled() andNumSamples:iPhoneGetOFWindow()->getAntiAliasingSampleCount() andRetina:iPhoneGetOFWindow()->isRetinaSupported()];
```

And it gives me a black screen if I `#define __COCOS2D__`.

**Where can I learn what I need to know** about `EAGLView` in order to `init` it in a way that makes both Cocos2D and openFrameworks happy?

Or, if you're feeling particularly saintly: **Why am I getting a black screen and what can I do about it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My working answer: Have only one of the frameworks (Cocos2D) do all the drawing. openFrameworks can handle modeling and so on behind the scenes, but doesn't actually ever set up an openGL context.

Still would love to hear if you've gotten them actually, fully, working together though...